# Angular platform-browser has no exported member 'MouseEvent'

Tags: angular, events, typescript, mouseevent

I am creating an angular 2 example to get mouse position and do some stuff according to mouse position (clientX).

I've found [this](https://embed.plnkr.co/Otz4l6/) example to get mouse positions. As shown in this example, I tried to import **MouseEvent** from **platformBrowser** as below:

```
 import {MouseEvent} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

It shows compilation error:
[image]

I Guess MouseEvent is not longer available in 'PlatformBrowser', Is there any other way to get mouse positions ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that's necessary, MouseEvent is an event type. It's for typescript typechecking. Just remove that import and try it like that.

Comment: what is the angular2 version in your app ?

Comment: Have you tried this http://www.angulartypescript.com/angular-2-events/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to import ,

Remove this line,

```
import {MouseEvent} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

You can just use

```
  private event: MouseEvent;
```